# erro SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, ejs

erro SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' in C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\src\views\layouts\layout01.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
at new Function ()
at Template.compile (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12)
at Object.compile (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:398:16)
at handleCache (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:235:18)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:16)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)

my app.ts

```
import fs from 'node:fs';
import path from 'node:path';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import express from 'express';
import layouts from 'express-ejs-layouts';
import i18n from 'i18n';

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

// Configurar Sentry
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'YOUR_SENTRY_DSN' });

// Configurar i18n
i18n.configure({
  locales: ['en', 'pt'],
  directory: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'locales'), // Corrigindo o caminho para a pasta de localização
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  cookie: 'lang',
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // Corrigindo o caminho para a pasta de views
app.use(layouts);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'))); // Corrigindo o caminho para a pasta de arquivos estáticos

app.use(i18n.init);

// Carregar o arquivo JSON
const domainData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('domains.json', 'utf-8'));

// Definir o layout para cada domínio
const domainLayouts: Record<string, string> = {};
for (const domain of domainData) {
  domainLayouts[domain.domain] = domain.layout;
}


// Middleware para selecionar o layout com base no domínio
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const domain = req.hostname;
  const layout = domainLayouts[domain] || 'layoutDefault'; // Layout padrão para domínios desconhecidos
  res.locals.layout = `layouts/${layout}`;
  next();
});

// Middleware para carregar o conteúdo do domínio
const domainContentMap: Record<string, { mainText: Record<string, string>; layout: string }> = {};
for (const domain of domainData) {
  domainContentMap[domain.domain] = {
    mainText: {
      en: 'Welcome to Site 1!',
      pt: 'Bem-vindo ao Site 1!',
    },
    layout: domain.layout,
  };
}

// Middleware para selecionar o conteúdo com base no domínio
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const domain = req.hostname;
  const content = domainContentMap[domain];
  if (content) {
    res.locals.content = content;
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(404).send('Página não encontrada');
  }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const lang = req.cookies.lang || 'en';
  const mainText = res.locals.content.mainText[lang];
  res.render('pages/index', {
    title: 'oi',
    mainText,
  });
});

// Lidar com erros
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());

// Iniciar o servidor
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor rodando na porta ${PORT}`);
});
```

domains.json

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "domain": "mcjars.pt",
      "layout": "layout01"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "domain": "steveshop.pt",
      "layout": "layout02"
    }
  ]
```

I tried putting it in a json file to see if the problem changes, but the same thing remains, I found something on the internet that didn't help at all, who can help, I'm a beginner

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide the contents of the `layout01.ejs` file, so we can see the problematic code

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the error is found in the file at `Users\bruno\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\DEV Bruno\devapi\node\src\views\layouts\layout01.ejs`. The error message is also saying that there's an unexpected token in that file. If you look in that file, you should see a `.` that is causing this error.

Comment: Hey, you have enough reputation to comment right? Do you wanna put that hard-earned rep on the line by providing a comment as an answer?